Seeking Advice on Efficient Data Unpivoting in SQL Server with SSIS or Alternative Tools
I'm currently working with a SQL Server database and facing a challenge with transforming my data. The data structure requires me to unpivot numerous columns before moving it to a staging area.
I attempted to use SSIS for this task. While I'm aware that SSIS can handle unpivoting, the process seems cumbersome because I have to manually specify each destination column, and with so many columns involved, it becomes infeasible to write all of them manually.
I initially considered using T-SQL for unpivoting, but my SSIS package doesn’t directly execute T-SQL scripts the way I intended.
I’ve read that there might be a way to leverage C# within SSIS to handle such transformations more efficiently. Is that true? Alternatively, are there any other tools or approaches that you would recommend for efficiently handling this kind of data transformation within the SQL Server environment, possibly still using SSIS?
example:
Original -data



catgry
item1
item2




One
Two
Three



Unpivoted-data-



catgry
items
value




One
item1
Tow


One
item2
Three



i do not want to write Unpivoted column names manually, i have more than 300 items.
Any tips or examples of similar experiences would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You can use raw sql for unpivoting too. Why not post some data and what you expect to accomplish, otherwise it's hard to give a good advice

i added an image. raw SQL will make me write the column names manually

Sample data as text is much more useful.

i added sample data as text

Here is an a sample using a bit of JSON (assuming 2016+).   Note we only have to filter columns LIKE 'ITEM%'
The JSON portion in the CROSS APPLY will UNPIVOT virtually any table, view or query.
Example or dbFiddle
Select A.ID
      ,A.FirstName
      ,A.LastName
      ,Item = B.[key]
      ,Value = B.Value
      ,A.CategoryID
      ,A.LocationID
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select * 
                From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                Where [Key] like 'Item%'
             ) B


Can you please take a look at my other question regarding your suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79002451/how-to-improve-execution-time-of-a-complex-sql-query-with-cte-and-cross-apply

@user27370924 Without an execution plan, I can't say.   What would be the runtime on the CTE alone?    The JSON portion is certainly less performant than an UNPIVOT, but then you would have to detail the 300 columns.

-- data preparation - - - - - - - - -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

declare @t table 
(
    catgry varchar(10) not null,
    item1 varchar(10) not null,
    item2 varchar(10) not null
);

insert into @t values ('One', 'Two', 'Three');

select * from @t;

-- solution - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

select
    t.catgry,
    item = i.item,
    value = case i.item 
                when 'item1' then t.item1 
                when 'item2' then t.item2 
            end
from
    @t t
    cross join (values ('item1'), ('item2')) i(item);


" i have more than 300 items"  This would be a long way to go  :)

Or perhaps cross apply (values ('item1', item1), ('item2', item2)) i(item, value) and lose the case expression. (But this still requires enumeration of all of the items. Dynamic SQL could be used, or if this is a one-off script, a good text editor and a regex replace.)
